# MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory or WebScriptServiceHostFactory for SharePoint 2010 Web Service?

Tags: .net, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

When it comes to creating a new Service running on SharePoint 2010, people seem to usually use the Sharepoint [MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx).

However, I would like to use the standard .net/WCF [WebScriptServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.webscriptservicehostfactory.aspx) instead because this gives me JavaScript code by calling the Service URL with /js.

My Service Class itself is still decorated with the required Attributes:

```
[BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =
         AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://mycompany/namespace")]
public class MyService : IMyServiceContract
```

The whole Service actually works fine, but I just wonder what the real differences are? What would the SharePoint ServiceHostFactory give me?

Comment: MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory isPerfectForThoseToughToReachPlaces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a great question! My curiosity finally got the better of me, and I started poking around in Reflector. It's not the authoritative final answer, but I think you'll be interested in what I learned.

First off: `MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory` simply generates `MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHost` objects; `WebScriptServiceHostFactory` simply generates `WebScriptServiceHost` objects.

Both hosts inherit `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost`, so they have a healthy base of common ground. Lucky for us, this reduces the size of the code footprint we must inspect to get a fair comparison.

Now, though there's not much new code in each class, they quickly branch off in different directions. Take a look at the `OnOpening()` implementations.

In `WebScriptServiceHost` we have:

```
base.OnOpening();
WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints(
    this,
    base.ImplementedContracts,
    SR2.GetString(SR2.JsonWebScriptServiceHostOneServiceContract, base.ImplementedContracts.Count));
foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in base.Description.Endpoints)
{
    if (endpoint.Binding != null &&
        endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements().Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>() != null &&
        endpoint.Behaviors.Find<WebHttpBehavior>() == null)
    {
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebScriptEnablingBehavior());
    }
}
```

Unless I am mistaken, the line reading `endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebScriptEnablingBehavior());` is responsible for the URL behavior (`/js`) you want.

Now, in `MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHost`, we have (abbreviated):

```
ClientServiceHost host = ClientServiceHost.CreateServiceHost();
this.CreateEndpoints();
base.OnOpening();
host.OnServiceHostOpeningInternal(this);
```

The differences between `WebServiceHost.AddAutomaticWebHttpBindingEndpoints()` and `this.CreateEndpoints()` were not abundantly clear to me. I got the impression that the SharePoint host contained more automatic configuration support for different authentication models.

`ClientServiceHost.CreateServiceHost()` is a factory method that creates a `ClientServiceHost` object based on a type listed in the  web.config section `microsoft.sharepoint.client/serverRuntime`.

The `OnServiceHostOpeningInternal()` method simply forwards the call to the host's `OnServiceHostOpening()` method. Looking at the web.config of a default install, we find the assembly qualified name for the service host type, from which we can inspect the method:

```
<serverRuntime>
  <hostTypes>
    <add type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPClientServiceHost, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </hostTypes>
</serverRuntime>
```

Here's where it gets interesting. The `OnServiceHostOpening()` method looks like this:

```
[SharePointPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, ObjectModel=true)]
protected override void OnServiceHostOpening(ServiceHost serviceHost)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        SPUtility.ConfigServiceHostIfClaimsAuth(serviceHost);
    }
}
```

Drilling in further, we see a metric boatload of logic surrounding configuring a host for claims-based authentication.

Aha! There is a difference worth noting. Unless I'm mistaken, there's no claims-based authentication support in `WebScriptServiceHost`.

### Conclusion

Perhaps you are not using claims-based authentication. If so, you might find that using `WebScriptServiceHost` is fine. However, were it me writing the service, I'd create a new host and host factory inheriting the Microsoft types, and see if I could create the /js extension by using `endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebScriptEnablingBehavior()`. The worst thing that could happen is that it wouldn't work. On the other hand, if it does work, you could expect to have a highly-SP-compatible service host factory that supports your endpoint preferences.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a very detailed explanation, especially the WebScriptingBehavior part is really useful!